# how to add curl_exec into database

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I want to use PHP and cURL to visits $i websites and add their source's into database.

```
  function curl_grab_page($site,$proxy,$proxystatus,$post)
  {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();      
    return curl_exec ($ch); 
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

So I use this function to get website sent in $post. As you can see, it returnes curl_exec($ch). Now I want to put curl_exec($ch) in database. How can I do it?

$sql = "INSERT INTO crawled (`website_source`) VALUES ('$str')";

and this doesn't work (returns die(); function, in this case it's obviously a blank page). Plz help. I don't see how else I could save content from websites. Preg_match doesnt work on curl_exec either. :/

Comment: curl_exec() returns TRUE or FALSE so the question makes little sense

Comment: What do u mean? It returnes the website's source code, and it is being executed when the website is opened. :/

Comment: may bad, i did not see that CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER was set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are actually grabbing the entire page via curl and storing in a string, you need to wrap it with a call to mysql_real_escape_string() to escape all the things that will screw up a SQL query like quotes and semicolons that might be in the page source...

```
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```

Good luck.  You might need to tweak your curl to get what you think you are getting as well...

Comment: Thank you, but I have an error: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_strings()

My PHP Version is 5.2.17

Comment: NVM :D It's mysql_real_escape_string(), not strings.

Comment: @MichałKról my bad it is string not strings http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

In your curl response, set the response to variables so you can troubleshoot:

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

Then you can view the $output and $info and determine what is returning.

As far as inserting into database, you will return your $output in the function and the calling code will have connection to database and execute insert query.  You will want your field type for website_source column as TEXT most likely.

```
// get connection to database

// iterate through list of websites to be crawled

// crawl site (call your function)
$page = curl_grab_page(...);

// check if content valid
if...blah

// insert into database
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO crawled ( website_source ) VALUES '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($page));

mysql_query($query);
```

You will probably want to surround with try catch and do some error handling.  msyql_real_escape_string works to protect against sql injection but I'm unsure if you also need to use addslashes($page) before inserting in case you get mysql failures.